# Html Storage resets every refresh, initialize function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a website I am working on, I am trying to keep information on how many items you buy to be shown across html pages. Researching how to do this has led me to believe that Html sessionStorage is the best way to do this (if there is a better/easier way please let me know). Yet, whenever I refresh the html page or go to another page the data resets.

Here is my code:

```
 function initialize(name, val) {
if(localStorage.getItem(name) === null) {
  localStorage.setItem(name, val);

   }

}

initialize("subCost", 0);
initialize("quantity", 0);
initialize("hasProduct", false);
```

Then since the storage only stores strings, I convert these into integers and boolean

```
var $quantity = parseInt(localStorage.quantity);
var $subCost = parseInt(localStorage.subCost);
var $hasProduct = localStorage.hasProduct == "true";
```

Before without the initialize function, I made the local storages items like this

```
localStorage.setItem("subCost", 0);
localStorage.setItem("quantity", 0);
localStorage.setItem("hasProduct", false);
```

and still converted these into those variable but they never saved with each refresh. How do I get these to save changes I make to them with each refresh.

Comment: Hey! That is a "double typo" !! Check how you wrote `initialize`! That fixed, your script works. [Look at the console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337) from time to time. ;)

Comment: Thank you, I did not see the typo, I am using TextEdit, now the rest of my jquery works with the function, but it still does not save with every refresh

Comment: Your code works in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yXpPOa?editors=0011). And it also works on page refresh. Your issue may be caused by something else.

Comment: Thank you for making that, I realized that in the rest of my code, I was making changes to the new variables, therefore the storage would not change, do you know how to make changes to a storage variable, because I have tried, as a test, replacing the `$quantity` variable with `parseInt(localStorage.quantity)` in one of my functions, with no success in saving the values. I also tried placing `localStorage.quantity = $quantity.toString();
localStorage.subCost = $subCost.toString();
localStorage.hasProduct = $hasProduct.toString();` at the end of my code, with again no success in saving.

Comment: It is tought to answer that question since I assume you already know how `localStorage.setItem(name,value)` works. Here is an update to my [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PjEEvO?editors=1011). Let me know if you find an answer in this example... **If not**, please edit your question with your HTML and full code.

Comment: Thank you very much, the code works now, I didn't realize I could just use `.setItem` to save the values, thanks.

Comment: Ha.. So what you were stucked on is the "set" word... `.setItem()` effectively sets a value if it doesn't exist... BUT it also overwrites it if it exists. I don't know how to post an answer on it... I have to think. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.setItem()` method on `localStorage` doesn't only "sets" a "memory placeholder" for a value... It also overwrites it, if it already exist.

To save the user generated values, the best "moment" to save a "change" is the `change` event.

Use the same `.setItem()` method as in your `initialize()` function.

```
$("input").on("change",function(){

  // Get id and value.
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var value = $(this).val();

  // Save!
  localStorage.setItem(id,value);
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PjEEvO?editors=1011)

---

**Just as a hint...**
This method to save values locally is ephemeral...
Values are kept until user closes the browser.
*Not just closing the page*, but closing the browser completely.
So to keep some values between pages navigated, this is the optimal use.

To store values for a longer run (like 6 months or longer), use cookies.
Have a look at [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).

Comment: Hoping this answer is complete... ;)